# Receive API application/octet-stream Post via PHP

Tags: php

I have post that comes from an iOS device. The header is that of:

```
application/octet-stream
```

I am trying to figure out in PHP how to receive that file. $_FILES seems to only work for:

```
multipart/form-data
```

Here is what we use to do:

```
if(isset($_FILES['media'])){
            $this->load->library( 'lib_files' );
            ini_set('max_execution_time', 300);
            $parts = pathinfo( $_FILES['media']['name'] );
            $result = $this->lib_files->move_file_into_structure( array(
                'project_id' => $project_id
                , 'current_path' => $_FILES['media']['tmp_name']
                , 'original_name' => $parts['filename']
                , 'extension' => $parts['extension']
                , 'insert_for' => 'mobile_journal_id'
                , 'insert_for_id' => $journal_id
                , 'user_id' => $user_project->user_id
            ) );
```

But now I am trying to grab octet-stream binary upload and I am confused how to do that here. So far I think I have to do something like this:

```
if($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == 'POST') {
            if($_POST == null) {
                $handle = fopen('php://input', 'r');
                $rawData = fgets($handle);
            }
        }
```

That rawData should be my file correct? How do I grab things like original_name, extension, current path I take it is php://input. I have never used octet-stream and I found nothing really online about doing it for php.